# Collections.sort() not sorting with compareTo Override

Tags: java

As the title states - here's my `Packet` class - I'm trying to sort into ascending order of `packetNum`:

```
public class Packet implements Comparable<Packet>{
    private short packetNum;
    private short authKey;
    private byte[] audio;

    public Packet()
    {
        packetNum = 0;
        authKey = 0;
        audio = null;
    }

    public Packet(short packetNum, short authKey, byte[] audio)
    {
        this.packetNum = packetNum;
        this.authKey = authKey;
        this.audio = audio;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Packet other) {
        int cmp = 0;
        if (this.packetNum < other.packetNum) {
            cmp = -1;
        }
        if (this.packetNum == other.packetNum) {
            cmp = 0;
        }
        else {
            cmp = 1;
        }
        return cmp;
    }
}
```

And here's my sorting code in another class' `main` (inside a while loop):

```
//Packet constructed
Packet received = new Packet(packetNumReceived, authKeyReceived, encryptedAudio);

//Get packet num
short packetNum = received.getPacketNum();

//Hold block for reordering (16 packets)
ArrayList<Packet> block = new ArrayList<Packet>();

while (running) {
    //Add packet to ArrayList
    block.add(received);
    System.out.println(packetNum);
    //Re-order packets
    if (block.size() == 16) {
        Collections.sort(block);
        for (int i = 0; i < block.size(); i++) {
            //print out the sorted packet numbers
            System.out.println(block.get(i).getPacketNum());
            player.playBlock(block.get(i).getAudio());
        }
        block.clear();
    }
}
```

The packet numbers printed are in the same (incorrect) order, before and after the sort. I've also check the array elements directly, and the order is not changed at all. These sections of code are the only time the Packet class is touched/referenced at all, not sure what I'm doing wrong. These are my only 2 classes, and there are no reused variable names across them.

Comment: `other.packetNum` shouldn't work, since `packetNum` is a `private` field. I would imagine this to not compile at all.

Comment: @Gendarme This isn't Smalltalk. The Packet class can look at private fields, even of other instances of itself.

Comment: Well, blimey! That's something.

Comment: As an aside: if you compare two object of same type `Type` by an `int`-field (say `x`), it is common to implement the `compareTo(Type that)` as `return this.x - that.x;`

Comment: @Turing85 that is exactly what Short.compare does

Comment: I would recommend to also implement an `equals` method to be consistent with `compareTo` - not the real problem here, but see documentation: *"It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals."*

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger and, of course, if one does so, one must also override `hashCode()`.

Comment: @Turing85 **I** know (despite *must*)

Comment: @Turing85 common, but wrong. It fails with extreme values. Use Integer.compare() or comparingInt().

Comment: @kumesana psst :) let them some brain teasters :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Packet other) {
    int cmp = 0;
    if (this.packetNum < other.packetNum) {
        cmp = -1;
    }
    if (this.packetNum == other.packetNum) {
        cmp = 0;
    }
    else {
        cmp = 1;
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

In this code, you are returning **1** if the comparison `this.packetNum == other.packetNum` evaluates to **false** even if you wanted to return **-1**.

You forgot an `else`:

```
    (...) 
    else if (this.packetNum == other.packetNum) {
        cmp = 0;
    }
    (...)
```

Comment: OK, confused by `gives you false` [:-)

Answer (score 3):

You're always returning `1` when the `packetNum` doesn't match because you're missing an `else if`.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Packet other) {
    int cmp = 0; // default to zero
    if (this.packetNum < other.packetNum) {
        cmp = -1;  // set to -1 in one case
    } // MISSING ELSE!
    if (this.packetNum == other.packetNum) {
        cmp = 0;  // set to zero if equal
    }
    else {
        cmp = 1;  // set to 1 if NOT EQUAL!
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

It's also true, as other have pointed out, that subtracting them or using `Short.compare` would make this code more terse and readable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't code what's already coded for you, use

```
Short.compare(this.packetNum, other.packetNum);
```

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#compare-short-short-)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: This answer the question by pointing OP to not reinvent the wheel and use what is already done. As you can see also other answers are now pointing to this

Comment: You can add comments to your answers (as David Conrad did), but you can't post comments as answers.

Comment: @Gendarme This is a perfectly valid answer. You would be suprised by how many people don't know about  this.

Comment: It can't be a valid answer if it doesn't answer the stated question. Can it? It's a fantastically helpful comment, but simply not an answer.

Comment: @Gendarme I might understand what you're saying. But what's the point of working on OP compareTo method if a **simpler and more efficient** alternative can be used instead?

Comment: A good answer would have a bit more substance: it would explain what's wrong with OPs version, and explain how to solve the issue in the most optimal way (ie show how to use your suggestion inside OPs code).

Comment: @rustyx understandable. However I think OP knows very well how to apply my one-liner inside his compareTo method. Anyway, I'll delete the answer shortly, I just wanted to express my opinion.